# Strike through each list item

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'm a few months into learning JavaScript and currently working on a shopping list project.

I want to be able to apply a strike through the list items when they are clicked on. However,after some time working on this, it does not allow me to do so. My attempt can be seen below in the function *removeNeedItem*. Can someone kindly have a look through my code and offer any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1><em>Shopping List</em></h1>
      <!-- Textbox -->
      <div class="form-wrap">
        <label><strong>Add Item: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="item-name" id="textbox" />
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="input-btn" id="need-btn">Need</button>
          <button class="input-btn" id="own-btn">Have</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Lists -->
      <h2 class="lists">Need to Buy</h2>
      <ul id="need-list"></ul>
      <h2 class="lists">Already Own</h2>
      <ul id="own-list"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```
var grocNeedList = [{ item: "Salmon", Required: true }];

function displayNeedList() {
  var needListUl = document.getElementById("need-list");
  needListUl.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < grocNeedList.length; i++) {
    grocNeedList[i].item;
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = grocNeedList[i].item;
    needListUl.appendChild(listItem);

    listItem.id = i;
    listItem.setAttribute("onclick", "removeNeedItem(event)");
  }
}

function removeNeedItem(event) {
  var position = event.currentTarget.id;
  position.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  displayGroc();
}

var addInput = document.getElementById("textbox");
needButton.addEventListener("click", addNeedItem);
```

Comment: `var position = event.currentTarget.id;` <--- um you read the id and you set the style of a string? ---> `position.style.textDecoration = "line-through";`

Comment: The developer console is your friend. There is probably an error telling you what epascarello found.

Comment: If it's like epascarello said, you're trying to change the style without selecting the target element. If this is the case, try `var position = document.querySelector(event.currentTarget.id)`

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the help. I'll have another look inspecting through the console.